# Destroying an object gives me an infinitive error loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a basic game for school and I'm stuck.

In the following update method (on an enemy) I am getting a boolean from my PlayerHealth script on my Player Object.

When I run out of health, I destroy the gameObject Player.
Because of that, my update method (on an enemy) keeps looping, in search of my playerObject that has been destroyed.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I was hoping an if/else statement would work but it doesn't.

```
 void Update()
 {
     if (!GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent <PlayerHealth>().deadPlayer) //false --> Chase
     {
         transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, chaseSpeed);  //move towards character
     } else
     {
         transform.position = transform.position;
     }
 }
```

Some extra info:

this is the error I am getting

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

But I know it is because the playerObject no longer exists. When doubleclicking it sends me to

```
if (!GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent <PlayerHealth>().deadPlayer) //false --> Chase
```

Can anyone help me?

Script where I change the value to true:

```
if (currentHealth <= 0)
{
    deadPlayer = true;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: You're getting the player object, then trying to access their health component. If you destroy the player, then you can't get the health component of something that's null. So, you'll have to ensure you get a valid player object before trying to access their health component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just check if the player exists?
`if (GameObject.Find("Player") != null)`

If you destroy an object, you can't access components on that object.

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't I think of that :/

Comment: @MeindertStijfhals ye, no worries. Fwiw, I made this mistake a few times when I first started.

Comment: I still make that mistake constantly.